# How to make combobox and label draggable in pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to create draggable 2 fields combobox and label field which have image (combobox + label(which have image)).

Single field I am able to make draggable but not able to do two fields as draggable.

Please suggest how to proceed?

Comment: Hi, Welcome, Please post your code.

Comment: You could explain what you want to get, your question is not clear, what do you want to drag and where? What is involved in the QComboBox and the QLabel? How do both elements interact?